# I am trying to improve the performance of this query can some one help me on this query

Tags: mysql, sql

### Query

```
select DISTINCT subscriber_data.* 
from subscriber_data, entities
where entities.id in 
(
   2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,
   15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,
   26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,1
) 
and Lower( subscriber_data.status) in ( 'active','expired')
and (subscriber_data.entity_uid = entities.channel_uid 
and subscriber_data.channel_id = entities.channel_id) 
and Lower( subscriber_data.status) in ( 'active','expired')
order by subscriber_data.land_size desc LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Reduce the performance? why would you want to do that?

Comment: edit your question and align the codes properly

Comment: its a back end query i need to optimize the above query

Answer (score 0):

First, rewrite the query without the `distinct` and fix your data so `status` has uniform case:

```
select sd.* 
from subscriber_data sd
where exists (select 1
              from entities e
              where e.id in (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,
                             26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,1
                            ) and 
                   sd.entity_uid = e.channel_uid  and
                   sd.channel_id = e.channel_id
             ) and
      sd.status in ( 'active', 'expired')
order by sd.land_size desc
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Then add the following indexes: `subscriber_data(status, land_size, entity_uid, channel_id)` and `entities(channel_uid, channel_id, id)`.

Comment: I have added indexes already SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the meanual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sd.status in ( 'active', 'expired')
order by sd.land_size desc
LIMIT 0, 10' at line 11 */

Comment: Help me on this query

Comment: U want me to add unique key index or normal key index

Comment: @SRI . . . If they are unique, you can add unique indexes.  But regular indexes will do.

Comment: with out adding subquery is any another way to optimize

Comment: What is the issue with the subquery?  It is saving the engine from having to do `distinct`.

Comment: no issue with the subquery but when testing with phpmyadmin they are unable to fix in php they have to change their entire coding

Comment: Is there any possibility to modify or change this query to reduce the performance